# Time Machine says "Waiting to Backup" after ML upgrade

Tags: backup, time-machine, upgrade, macos

I just upgraded to ML and my Time Machine says "Waiting to Backup".

Is the cause of this got to do anything with Spotlight indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Index was slowing down TM as well, but TM was just being slow overall and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You should be able to click the Time Machine icon, then *Open Time Machine Preferences...* and then it will tell you a more detailed reason such as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing here. In the Time Machine preferences, you have the list of your drives plus an icon labeled *Add or Remove Backup Disk*. In this list, right click on the icon of the disk and select *Back Up to "..." Now*. That worked for me.