# Time Machine says “Waiting” for any backup copy.

Tags: time-machine, macos

I run three backups on three different drives and I can't excess any of them after installation of El Capitan. 
What to do?
Gert G.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57719/time-machine-says-waiting-to-backup-after-ml-upgrade?rq=1

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit, especially can you not *access* your existing backup history **or** does TM seem to be stuck in "Waiting"?

Comment: Hi! When I activate TM I get this normal StarWars screen, when I go back to ANY of the previous copies it stucks on 'waiting'.